# Discord.JS | How can I create an argument that is specifically under []

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm actually trying to create an announce command in my discord bot, but I want it to have an argument under [ ] which would be the announce name (ex: `!announce [announce name] announce content`) but I really don't know how to do it, I've tryed to search many sites but none of them explained my question.

Here is the code if needed:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let canal = message.mentions.channels.first()

  if(!canal) {
    return message.channel.send("Por favor, ponha um canal para que eu possa anunciar.")
  } else {
    const canal = args.shift().slice(2,-1);
    const mensagem = args.join(" ");

    bot.channels.cache.get(canal).send(`:scroll: **| Anúncio Oficial**\n\n${mensagem}\n\n||@everyone|| - ${message.author}/${message.author.username}`);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "announce name"

Comment: It's what will appear instead of "Anúncio Oficial" in ```bot.channels.cache.get(canal).send(`:scroll: **| Anúncio Oficial**\n\n${mensagem}\n\n||@everyone|| - ${message.author}/${message.author.username}`);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's in your "args" so I'll just approach this using regex and message.content.
This is how you can extract announce name and announce content from the input string:

```
let reg = /!(.*) \[(.*)\] (.*)/g;
let result = reg.exec(message.content);
if(result === null) return console.log("Incorrect format");
let announceName = result[2];
let announceContent = result[3];

// if message.content = "!announce [announce name] announce content"
// then announceName = "announce name" and announceContent = "announce content"
```

You can paste the regex into https://regex101.com/ to test it out.